# Display static warning message upon LWC's creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, toast

Is it possible to display a warning toast event msg whenever a component is created?

Basically, without triggering it in any way, like with a btn click.

.js

```
showMsg(){
 const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
  title: 'Toast Warning',
  message: 'Warning!',
  variant: 'warning',
  mode: 'sticky'
 });
 this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

.html

```
<div class="warning" onnotification={showMsg}></div>
```

'Cause right now it obviously isn't working.

If not with an event, how can I achieve that? (Trying to avoid custom css)

Comment: Did you try calling `this.showMsg()` from the `connectedCallback` on your LWC?

Comment: @PhilW Just did, nothing happens.

Comment: @samdev Yep, it is imported. I dunno why it doesn't work with connectedCallback, I tried renderedCallback as well since this is a child component and gets fired from the parent on certain conditions. But anyway, I figured now I'll just use ```slds-notify``` and get it done get it over with :) Thanks for your time both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, my bad, I am using this component embedded in a VF page through an aura wrapper app so what I was trying to do wouldn't work. I will make it work with `slds-notify` instead.